# Does GeoJSON spec imply that polygons should be simple?

Tags: geojson

If we read 3.1.6 of RFC7946 one may think GeoJSON implicitly requires polygons to be [simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon). For example:

> A linear ring MUST follow the right-hand rule with respect to the
>   area it bounds, i.e., exterior rings are counterclockwise, and
>   holes are clockwise.

From this statement we may infer that we must not change the winding direction of a polygon thus may not anticipate twisted polygons (like the rightmost one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#/media/File:Assorted_polygons.svg)).

Also:

> For Polygons with more than one of these rings, the first MUST be
>   the exterior ring, and any others MUST be interior rings.  The
>   exterior ring bounds the surface, and the interior rings (if
>   present) bound holes within the surface.

It seems from this paragraph we can decide not to anticipate holes of a polygon to intersect with polygon itself.

Considering all this, can we assume that polygons stored in well-formed GeoJSON are simple or at least with simple exterior and interior contours?